# How to add a Resource or Endpoint in a CoAP server program Golang

Tags: go, client-server, coap

https://github.com/dustin/go-coap

I am using the above library for Building a Server-Client programs in Golang.
How can we add a Resource or Endpoint on Server Side and write a Handler in-specific to that endpoint.

And also how to Publish data to specific Resource or Endpoint from client Side.

Can someone give examples using the above library.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

The sample code of [client](https://github.com/dustin/go-coap/blob/master/example/client/goap_client.go) and [server](https://github.com/dustin/go-coap/blob/master/example/server/coap_server.go) are under ./example/

Comment: I am expecting for an example of server-client which makes use of End-points.